# Really simple PHP/PDO insert not working?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Getting really confused with PDO now!

Im trying to just insert anything into my table, only i cant, I have the following connection file...

```
<?php

$username = 'access@site.co';
$password = 'access';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site_co_uk', $username, $password);
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

?>
```

and my php is...

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once ('connection.php');

$STH = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users ( firstname ) values ( 'Cathy' )");  
$STH->execute(); 

?>
```

Nothing is inserted into my table, is there any reason why this could be happening?!

Answer (score 4):

Remove this:

`$dbh = null;`

It's setting your DB connection to null.